# Angular 2/4 Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am a beginner with Angular 2 and have some questions:

Q#1 I have a method (which is placed in component), for instance "Get". It returns Observable with Array of strings. In this method I use angular's HTTP module which sends get request to backend:

```
this.http.get("some_URL").map(resp =><Array<string>>resp.json()).subscribe(items =>{
    this.items = items; //private component's variable
    this.subject.next(this.items); //private component's subject
});
return this.subject.asObservable(); //returns subject as observable
```

So, what I am doing here is just send GET request and before getting the result I return my Subject as Observable. Some code, which calls Get method subscribes on my "subject as observable", and when Get method gets result from backend it calls next and passes there the data which it got. Please correct me if I wrong, but I hope I have a clear understanding of how to use Observables.

Q#2 Lets assume I have another method GetById which accepts id:number and returns string. Would it be correct if I created a local BehaviorSubject variable in this method? So, every time when someone calls this method the new BehaviorSubject will be created and returned for subscription. Can it somehow has a bad influence on memory or performance?

```
var tmpSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    this.http.get("some_URL").map(resp => resp.json()).subscribe(item =>{
        tmpSubject.next(item);
    });

return tmpSubject.asObservable();
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:

There is a much better way of doing this. Do something like this:

```
let observable = this.http.get("some_URL").map(resp =><Array<string>>resp.json()).cache();

let subscription = observable.subscribe(items =>{
    this.items = items; //private component's variable
    this.subject.next(this.items); //private component's subject
});

return observable; //returns subject as observable
```

In Q2, there is no need for you to create a BehaviouralSubject either. You rarely create observables yourself. And `http.get` returns an observable. So just use it! If you want to call `get` once but subscribe to it in multiple places, the use something like `cache` (I think it might have been droppen in newer versions of rxjs, but there is an alternative).

Also, a good pattern is to unsubscribe to your subscriptions. So subscribing should only be done in Angular `@Component`s and you should add `.unsubscribe` to `OnDestroy` hook. This gives a great explanation of the issue in detail: http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

And in general, the best pattern I found to be is that you create a service class, that exposes get/post/whatever methods, that all return `Observable`s of any kind. Then you only subscribe to them in your components (or directives). They have `OnDestroy` hooks that will allow you to unsubscribe and not leak memory.

It would look something like:

```
export class SomeService {

    function getSomething(param: any): Observable<SomeType> { ... }

}
```

...

```
@Component
export class SomeComponent extends OnDestroy {

    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private service: SomeService) {
        this.subscription = service.getSomething(123).subscribe(...);
    }


    function ngOnDestroy(){
        if(this.subscription) {
            this.subscription.unsubcribe();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Q1 answer is not clear for me. Do you mean that I should return the observable from `get` method instead of creating my own? Something like this: 
`let observable = this.http.get("some_URL").map(resp =><Array<string>>resp.json()).cache();
return observable;`

Comment: Yes indeed, that is what I meant!

Comment: But best use the pattern at the bottom of my answer :)

Comment: ok I got it! Thank you for your description of unsubscribing.

But what if I call `getById` and the backend returns me empty string or 404 HTTP code? I believe it is more correct to add some extra logic into my service rather then in components which are using my service? Am I right? I mean that in case of 404 it would be more convenient if my service returns empty object rather than `undefine`, `null`, etc

Comment: 1. For all of the transformations that you want to do in the service, just use transforming methods: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#transforming. 2. 404 and all other HTTP errors will go to `error` handler, so just display an error to an end user, when you subscribe to observable in a component. 3. In case you want to recover from some errors (e.g. 404 is not really an error, but more of an empty result), you can use error handling methods: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#error